# FragmentManager: No field with the name mListener is found in Animation class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got error when detaching (removing) a `Fragment` from my `FragmentManager`.

**Detaching:**

```
public void onFragmentDetached(String tag) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .disallowAddToBackStack()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_right)
                    .remove(fragment)
                    .commitNow();
            unlockDrawer();
        }
}
```

**Attaching:**

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .disallowAddToBackStack()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_right)
                .replace(R.id.mainRootView, settingsFragment, SettingsFragment.TAG)
                .commit();
```

Here is my error:

```
E/FragmentManager: No field with the name mListener is found in Animation class
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mListener in class Landroid/view/animation/Animation; (declaration of 'android.view.animation.Animation' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getAnimationListener(FragmentManager.java:1301)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.animateRemoveFragment(FragmentManager.java:1638)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1548)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:648)
        at com.fearefull.todoreminder.ui.main.MainActivity.onFragmentDetached(MainActivity.java:148)
        at com.fearefull.todoreminder.ui.settings.SettingsFragment.goBack(SettingsFragment.java:71)
        at com.fearefull.todoreminder.ui.settings.SettingsViewModel.onNavigationBackClick(SettingsViewModel.java:23)
        at com.fearefull.todoreminder.databinding.FragmentSettingsBindingImpl._internalCallbackOnClick(FragmentSettingsBindingImpl.java:188)
        at com.fearefull.todoreminder.generated.callback.OnClickListener.onClick(OnClickListener.java:11)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

I'm using SDK version 29, How can I fix this?

Comment: show full stacktrace

Comment: my selectedFragment(SettingsFragment) calls The MainActivity to detach itself. And MainActivity calls the `onFragmentDetached` method.

Comment: Looks like Listener class in Animation was added to greylist in SDK 29

Comment: @Aref did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into exactly the same thing under very similar circumstances.

Comment: The only solution I've found is to remove the `setCustomAnimations` calls, but then there's no animation.

Comment: @DavidBerry nah buddy, I cannot find any solution for this error. Maybe further version of SDK 29 can solve this issue.

Comment: Just in case it helps, and given it's the same exception, I just created https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140001342

Comment: We have the same error on Pixel 3 device with Android Q, no Problem with Pixel 1 and Android Q

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in newer versions of `androidx.fragment` as mentioned in [bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139349998) someone made due to existing issue.

Answer (score 4):

to simply put, just add below line to your build.gradle(:app),
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.3"