# No field with the name mListener is found in Animation class

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-animation, navigation-drawer

**Navigation Activity**

```
class NavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_notes, R.id.nav_reminder, R.id.nav_archive,
            R.id.nav_deleted, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(p0: MenuItem): Boolean {

    when(p0.itemId) {
        R.id.nav_notes -> {
            HomeFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_reminder -> {
            GalleryFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_archive -> {
            SlideshowFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_deleted -> {
            ToolsFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_share -> {
            ShareFragment()
        }
        R.id.nav_send -> {
            SendFragment()
        }
        else -> {
            HomeFragment()
        }
    }

    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}
```

}

Getting error when navigation happens
**ERROR**

```
 W/ple.my_note_ap: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/animation/Animation;->mListener:Landroid/view/animation/Animation$AnimationListener; (greylist-max-p, reflection, denied)
E/FragmentManager: No field with the name mListener is found in Animation class
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field mListener in class Landroid/view/animation/Animation; (declaration of 'android.view.animation.Animation' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getAnimationListener(FragmentManager.java:1301)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.setHWLayerAnimListenerIfAlpha(FragmentManager.java:1283)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1811)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2426)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2372)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I am getting this error when navigation happens from one fragment to another fragment.
But it does not cause program to crash but when create complex hierarchy of layouts it does not show some layouts from xml.
So how to solve this error
So Any solution for this error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR  is shown above-No field with the name mListener is found in Animation class

Comment: Let me know if you want more information

Comment: Are you targeting SDK 29?

Comment: yes - I am targeting  SDK 29

Comment: Possible Android bug:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57345966/fragmentmanager-no-field-with-the-name-mlistener-is-found-in-animation-class

Comment: Sounds like a version mismatch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug in `androidx.fragment` that is fixed in `1.1.0-alpha07` and newer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139349998.  Ensure that you are on at least that version (instructions can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment)).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but, in my case, wasn't using androidx.

I solved it moving the Button creation and the setOnClickListener event from
onCreate() to the onCreateView() method.

Hope It helps someone, best regards!